# Getting properties from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm receiving a JSON object and need to select a property out of it, but the key is split with a "."

```
metrics: {
    site.hardware: {
      values: []
    }
}
```

When selecting `metrics.site.hardware.values` I'm getting a cannot read properties error. This make sense to me as it is looking for the `hardware` value within `site`. How do I select `values` within the `site.hardware` property?

Comment: Try wrapping site.hardware in square brackets like this metrics.[site.hardware].values

Comment: Thank you all. This is the answer I was looking for.